# How open only one window "Preferences"?

Tags: objective-c, macos

My app have Preferences window. I open it using this code

```
- (IBAction)openPreferences:(id)sender {

    NSWindowController *windowController = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Preferences"];
    [windowController window];
}
```

If press **command,** again-again and again new Preferences window will be opened again-again and again...

How open only one window? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make windowController a instance variable of your AppDelegate and change your open preferences to

```
- (IBAction)openPreferences:(id)sender
{
    if( windowController == nil )
        windowController = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Preferences"];
    [windowController showWindow:sender];
}
```

Comment: I need help! When i use code above this comment, in my app i may open only one Preferences window. That's right!!! But! When i close him, and press "command," again this have not effect. How fix it?

Comment: In interface builder for that window, make sure 'Release when Closed' is unchecked, that way the preferences window his just hidden hidden when closed.

Comment: No. This is not work. windowController=nil and method showWindow failed.

Comment: Where is this code defined it sounds like you are ending up with more than one instance of the class openPreferences: is defined. You should put it in you app delegate and then create an instance of your app delegate in your main nib, that way only one is created for you when you app starts up.

Comment: Yes. I put this code in AppDelegate class only. But after open preferences window instance variable windowController don't nill, and after closed pref window windowController don't nill. This is right? If that wrong i don't understand what i do.

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I solved it...
I have a class "MyPreferencesWindowController" which has a method called `getInstance`.  This method is what is called when you want to get the preferences window.  This solution takes advantage of singleton technology.

```
/**
Method in my MyPreferencesWindowController.m file
with a corresponding method in the .h file.
*/
+(id) getInstance {

    static PreferencesWindowController *instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return instance;
}
```

Now in the Document class, when you want to show the preferences window, do the following:

```
-(IBAction) showPreferences:(id)sender {
    if (preferencesWc  == nil)
        preferencesWc = [MyPreferencesWindowController getInstance];

    [ preferencesWc showWindow:self ];
}
```

This will ensure the preferences window is only created once.  And then each call to `getInstance` will return the same instance of the window.